# Python 2 detects exception outside except block but not Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, gunicorn

I found this piece of code detecting exception within the try block itself when run in python 2.

```
import sys
for i in range(3):
    try:
        if sys.exc_info()[1]:
            print("Exception found")
        else:
            print("Exception not found")
        raise Exception("Random exception")
    except Exception as e:
        pass
```

Output generated by python 2.7.17 -

```
Exception not found
Exception found
Exception found
```

When run on python 3, the exception is not detected. 
Output generated by python 3.7.7 -

```
Exception not found
Exception not found
Exception not found
```

Why does python 2 behave this way? Is there any workaround in python 2 to avoid this behavior? 
Wrong exception detection is throwing off my application's logging when run using gunicorn.

Comment: `sys.exc_info` shouldn't be used outside an `except` block, precisely because there's no reason to expect an unhandled exception to be lying around. The Python 3 behavior may be related to the fact that `e` is unset once the `except` block exits.

Comment: @chepner The problem I'm facing is that `log.exception` is printing the stacktrace of an exception that isn't even being handled. This is unexpected behavior and quite misleading.

Comment: It's being handled, or your interpreter would have exited. The problem is that you are *ignoring* an exception.

Comment: By "isn't even being handled", I meant we are not in the except block which is supposed to handle the exception. Even though we are not currently handling that exception (it has already been handled), our logging signifies that we are handling that exception.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the meaning of "handling an exception" there is a difference between Python 2 and Python 3 in this context. It's best visualized with a diff of the relevant docs entry ([Py2](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/sys.html#sys.exc_info) vs. [Py3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exc_info)):

[image: Docs diff]

So while in Python 3 this definition includes only the *exception being currently handled*, in Python 2 also the *most recently handled exception* is included.